# Changing propieties of 2 objects from same base class, python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I´m trying to make a simpler interface of `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `scipy`, etc.. for my experimental physics course. I made a class named `E_dat`, that takes some data and uncertanties and can return statistical information of the data, like max, min, standard deviation... this is the class:

```
class E_Dat(object):

    def __init__(self, data, error = None, data_type = "foo"):
        self.data = np.array(data)
        self.error = np.array(error)
        self.shape = self.data.shape
        self.Mean = np.mean(data)
        self.Max = np.max(data)
        self.Min = np.min(data)
        self.STD = np.std(data)
        self.data_type = data_type

        if self.data.shape != self.error.shape and self.data_type != "foo":
            raise ValueError('data.shape y error.shape no coinciden')

        if self.data_type == "2d_plot" and self.data.ndim != 2:
            raise ValueError('data.shape no es 2d, no puede graficarse')

        if self.data_type == "hist" and self.data.ndim != 1:
            pass

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_error(self):
        return self.error

    def get_shape(self):
        return self.shape

    def get_mean(self):
        return self.Mean

    def get_max(self):
        return self.Max

    def get_min(self):
        return self.Min

    def get_std(self):
        return self.STD
```

Now i wanted to make a `Plot` class, for simple plots so i don´t have to make the code every time, and the `Plot` class would inherit properties from the `E_Dat` class, i don´t know how to approach that class, because for example i would need two 1D `E_Dat` objects from the same base class and i can only inherit one object from the same class. Can i inherit from a list of objects from the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem you need inheritance here:

```
class MyPlot():

    def __init__(self, e_dat1, e_dat2):
        self.e_dat1 = e_dat1
        self.e_dat2 = e_dat2
```

With `e_dat1` and `e_dat2` two `E_Dat` objects.

Comment: Thank you! I was a bit confused about inheritance, i know i don´t need it for this is specific case but, a Class can inherit froma list of objects?

Comment: In Python, a `class` can only inherit from one other `class`

Comment: Ok i´ll need to read a bit more, can you recommends any good bibliography about classes?